# VERCEL Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/404.html

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, enoent

I have a problem with

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/404.html'

when vercel is building nextjs project

> Traced Next.js server files in: 679.461ms Created all serverless
> functions in: 1.424s Collected static files (public/, static/,
> .next/static): 16.604ms Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/404.html'
>
> info  - Generating static pages (33/33) info  - Finalizing page
> optimization... Route (pages)
> Size     First Load JS ┌ ● /
> 25.9 kB         232 kB ├   └ css/eb4ce053ae4f7359.css                     2.41 kB ├   /_app                                          0 B             160 kB ├ ○ /404                                           355 B
> 160 kB ├ ○ /500                                           291 B
> 160 kB ├ ● /account                                       2.68 kB
> 214 kB

Can somebody help me on this, did anybody face with same problem?

[image]

I have tried to delete `404.js` and build the project, and it works but as, I am trying to use custom404 page and on my other projects I've used the same method nextJS recommends, which is creating `404.js` inside pages folder in next project, but somehow on my current project suddently vercel started to show this error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/404.html'

I deleted `404.js`, created again, but same error...

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.